# Converting Unicode string to Chinese characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

How can I convert the following Unicode string to Chinese characters?

The string is:

```
'\\u5982\\u679c\\u6211\\u662f\\u4e00\\u4e2a\\u4ece\\u524d\\u7684\\u54f2\\u4eba\\uff0c\\u6765\\u5230\\u4eca\\u5929\\u7684\\u4e16\\u754c\\uff0c\\u6211\\u4f1a\\u6700\\u6000\\u5ff5\\u4ec0\\u4e48\\uff1f'
```

And I want it to be:

```
如果我是一个从前的哲人，来到今天的世界，我会最怀念什么？
```

Comment: Did you try looking at what the function is doing?

Comment: `line.strip(u'<sentence S=">')` is the same as `line.strip(u'=<>"censSt ')`. It'll strip the characters in any order.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I want to extract the desired sentence from the file through get_str_segmented function. but the extracted sentence was not in chinese but '\u5982\u679c\u6211\u662f\u4e00'.

Comment: I didn't ask what it was *supposed* to do, I asked what it was *doing*.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it returns unicode? and I want it displayed in chinese, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Decode it using `unicode-escape` will give you what you want.

### Python 2.7

```
>>> print '\\u5982\\u679c\\u6211\\u662f\\u4e00\\u4e2a\\u4ece\\u524d\\u7684\\u54f2\\u4eba\\uff0c\\u6765\\u5230\\u4eca\\u5929\\u7684\\u4e16\\u754c\\uff0c\\u6211\\u4f1a\\u6700\\u6000\\u5ff5\\u4ec0\\u4e48\\uff1f'.decode('unicode-escape')
如果我是一个从前的哲人，来到今天的世界，我会最怀念什么？
```

### Python 3.x

```
>>> print('\\u5982\\u679c\\u6211\\u662f\\u4e00\\u4e2a\\u4ece\\u524d\\u7684\\u54f2\\u4eba\\uff0c\\u6765\\u5230\\u4eca\\u5929\\u7684\\u4e16\\u754c\\uff0c\\u6211\\u4f1a\\u6700\\u6000\\u5ff5\\u4ec0\\u4e48\\uff1f'.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))
如果我是一个从前的哲人，来到今天的世界，我会最怀念什么？
>>> print(b'\\u5982\\u679c\\u6211\\u662f\\u4e00\\u4e2a\\u4ece\\u524d\\u7684\\u54f2\\u4eba\\uff0c\\u6765\\u5230\\u4eca\\u5929\\u7684\\u4e16\\u754c\\uff0c\\u6211\\u4f1a\\u6700\\u6000\\u5ff5\\u4ec0\\u4e48\\uff1f'.decode('unicode-escape'))
如果我是一个从前的哲人，来到今天的世界，我会最怀念什么？
```