# How to use Python convert a unicode string to the real string

Tags: python, json, unicode, web-crawler

I have used Python to get some info through `urllib2`, but the info is unicode string.

I've tried something like below:

```
a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
print unicode(a).encode("gb2312")

a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
print a.encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")

a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
print u""+a

a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
print str(a).decode("utf-8")

a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
print str(a).encode("utf-8")

a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
print a.decode("utf-8").encode("gb2312")
```

but all results are the same:

```
\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728
```

And I want to get the following Chinese text:

```
方法，删除存储在
```

Comment: Which python version are you using? Maybe you need `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​My answer: Just use Python 3 and the `a` will be your expected string and you don't need convert it yourself.

Comment: Maybe the console only supports ascii characters?

Comment: And also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688020/how-to-print-chinese-word-in-my-code-using-python). Oh hey, [there's also another way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371953/python-2-7-converting-unicode-to-chinese-character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `string` to a `unicode string`.

First of all, the backslashes in `a` are auto-escaped:

```
a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"

print a # Prints \u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728

a       # Prints '\\u65b9\\u6cd5\\uff0c\\u5220\\u9664\\u5b58\\u50a8\\u5728'
```

So playing with the encoding / decoding of this escaped string makes no difference.

You can either use `unicode literal` or convert the string into a `unicode string`.

To use `unicode literal`, just add a `u` in the front of the string:

```
a = u"\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
```

To convert existing `string` into a `unicode string`, you can call `unicode`, with `unicode_escape` as the `encoding` parameter:

```
print unicode(a, encoding='unicode_escape') # Prints 方法，删除存储在
```

I bet you are getting the `string` from a `JSON` response, so the second method is likely to be what you need.

BTW, the `unicode_escape` encoding is a Python specific encoding which is used to

> Produce a string that is suitable as Unicode literal in Python source
>   code

Comment: Yes, `unicode_escape` seems the way to go.

Comment: thanks you very very much !!!!

Comment: `a = '\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728'
print(unicode(a, encoding='unicode_escape'))` build error in python3 with " decoding str is not supported",which unicode module should i import or i should by another way in python3? thanks very much!

Comment: how to implement this in python3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting this data from? Perhaps you could share the method by which you are downloading and extracting it.

Anyway, it kind of looks like a remnant of some JSON encoded string? Based on that assumption, here is a very hacky (and not entirely serious) way to do it:

```
>>> a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
>>> a
'\\u65b9\\u6cd5\\uff0c\\u5220\\u9664\\u5b58\\u50a8\\u5728'
>>> s = '"{}"'.format(a)
>>> s
'"\\u65b9\\u6cd5\\uff0c\\u5220\\u9664\\u5b58\\u50a8\\u5728"'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(s)
u'\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728'
>>> print json.loads(s)
方法，删除存储在
```

This involves recreating a valid JSON encoded string by wrapping the given string in `a` in double quotes, then decoding the JSON string into a Python unicode string.