# How to correct one unicode string like "\u8bf8\u845b\u4eae" in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I don't know how they printed strings like "\u8bf8\u845b\u4eae" to  the log files. But now i need to get the correct string from it, it is "诸葛亮" in chinese. I have tried many ways, but failed.

```
In [56]: print u"\u8bf8\u845b\u4eae"
诸葛亮

In [57]: print "\u8bf8\u845b\u4eae"
\u8bf8\u845b\u4eae

In [58]: "\u8bf8\u845b\u4eae".decode('utf-8')
Out[58]: u'\\u8bf8\\u845b\\u4eae'
In [64]: eval("\u8bf8\u845b\u4eae")
  File "<string>", line 1
    \u8bf8\u845b\u4eae
                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: it is not clear what is your input exactly? (is it a file on the disk that contains `\u8bf8..`  literally? i.e., if you open the file in a text editor you see `\u...`). Is it in a variable (that gets assigned by some API)? The correct way is to use `u"\u8bf8..."` and never `"\u8bf8..."` in Python 2 unless `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is in effect. Do you want to save `u"\u8bf8.."`  in a file?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Sorry, it's the first case, a file on the disk that contains \u8bf8.. literally. I read the unicode literals from a log file, which is printed in a bad manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use: `unicode-escape`

```
print '\\u8bf8\\u845b\\u4eae'.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

also see: [Converting Unicode string to Chinese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371953/converting-unicode-string-to-chinese-characters)