# Python chinese characters

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I have the following encoding in python 2.7:

```
["\xe5\x81\x9a\xe6\x88\x8f\xe4\xb9\x8b\xe8\xaf\xb4"]
```

I need to get the following (chinese characters) from that:

```
["做戏之说"]
```

Anyone knows how to decode the above to get that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correct one unicode string like ("\u8bf8\u845b\u4eae" in python?)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439567/how-to-correct-one-unicode-string-like-u8bf8-u845b-u4eae-in-python]

Comment: @elabard: how is that addressing decoding a UTF-8 string? The answer there is **not** applicable here.

Comment: It is asking basically the same thing...anyway also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371953/converting-unicode-string-to-chinese-characters

Comment: @Nana: you shoudn't have UTF8-encoded bytes in a list, you should decode to unicode, when you read your bytes.

Comment: @elabard: your «duplicates» are dealing with unicode-strings not with utf8-encoded bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode your string:

```
>>> l = ["\xe5\x81\x9a\xe6\x88\x8f\xe4\xb9\x8b\xe8\xaf\xb4"]
>>> a = [l[0].decode('utf8')]
>>> print a[0]
做戏之说
```

If you want to show your Unicode inside the list you need to convert the standard representation of the list to unicode then print it:

```
>>> print unicode(repr([l[0].decode('utf8')]), 'unicode-escape')
[u'做戏之说']
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried this before and I got \u505a\u620f\u4e4b\u8bf4 this

Comment: That's the representation of unicode codepoints. Kasravand has showed, that printing the strings lead to the correct display.