# How to print a real chinese string from unicode string in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, unicode, utf-8

I have some unicode string  like:

```
a = '\u534e\u590f\u6210\u957f\u6df7\u5408'
```

When I print it, I want to convert it to a real chinese string, not '\uxxxx'.

How could I implement this ?

Comment: on win 10, python 3.7, when I am printing `a` I am getting: `华夏成长混合`. What output are you getting?

Comment: ... btw, what is `China Growth Hybrid`? I am just curious :) !

Comment: That's not the string you have, if `print(a)` shows `\u5343...`.  It would need to be `a = '\\u53re..'`.  What do you *really* have?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x? I know the tag is Python 3.x, yet I have my doubts!

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371953/converting-unicode-string-to-chinese-characters

Comment: Thanks to you people, I found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371953/converting-unicode-string-to-chinese-characters